# Deserialize JSON that could be an array or a single item

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using an API from a 3rd-party that returns different JSON results from the same endpoint depending on how many results there are. If there is a single result the response is:

```
{
  "data": {
  ...
  },
  "metadata": {
  ...
  }
}
```

However if the result has more than one the response is:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "data": {...},
        "metadata": {...}
    }, {
        "data": {...},
        "metadata": {...}
    }],
    "metadata": {...}
}
```

I'm using C# and Json.Net and can't work out how to dynamically handle this mixed response. Is there a way to deserialize these responses with Json.net?

Comment: This API is full of sadness when it comes to consistency....

Comment: Don't get me started.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not write something like this:

```
public class root 
{
    public Item data { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> items { get; set; }
    public MetaData metadata { get; set; }
}
```

And then check whether `items` or `data` is null when processing

Comment: This seems to work but does require that I check each time to see if there are multiple results. I'm curious if there is a better way. Ie. Change the response to always be an array before deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.net has the JObject related classes that are handy for being a little less rigid and a bit more dynamic in nature. This allows you to (for instance):

```
var item = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var hasItems = item.Properties().Any(p => p.Name == "items");
if(hasItems)
{
    var items = item["items"].Select(t => t.ToObject<SomeClass>());
}
else
{
    var sc = item.ToObject<SomeClass>();
}
```